# I want to compare a text of red color background of two different web pages using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to compare a text of red color background of two different web pages using selenium webdriver. If both are same then it should display true else false. Please help me out to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `.getCssValue("background-color");` which can be called for a WebElement, and then use an assert statement to check that this value is equal to "red".